# Syntax error trying to create an Stored Procedure in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to create an stored procedure in MySQL but when I try, phpmyadmin tell me that I have a Syntax error. Why? I was searching that the issue could be because i have CASE statements within my if else conditions, but as a far as I know, this is so insane and I hope you can help me and tell me what's my problem whit this Stored Procedure in Mysql. Thanks.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE extraer_fechas(
    statusFecha SMALLINT(5),
    string_busqueda VARCHAR(50)
)
BEGIN

IF string_busqueda = "false" THEN
    SELECT
        CONCAT(fechas.year,'-',fechas.month,'-',fechas.dates) AS fecha_php,
        fechas.ID, 
        fechas.dates, 
        fechas.month, 
        fechas.year, 
        paises.nombre AS city,
        fechas.region, 
        fechas.place, 
        fechas.tickets, 
        fechas.directions, 
        fechas.flyer,
        seo_sitemap.title,
        seo_sitemap.description,
        seo_sitemap.url,
        seo_sitemap.array_tags
            FROM fechas 
                INNER JOIN paises ON fechas.city = paises.id_pais 
                INNER JOIN seo_sitemap ON seo_sitemap.id_articulo = fechas.ID
            WHERE seo_sitemap.id_tabla = 1
            AND fechas.status_fecha = statusFecha
        ORDER BY 
        fechas.month,
        fechas.dates,
        fechas.year 

ELSE
    SELECT 
        CONCAT(fechas.year,'-',fechas.month,'-',fechas.dates) AS fecha_php,
        fechas.ID, 
        fechas.dates, 
        fechas.month, 
        fechas.year, 
        paises.nombre AS city,
        fechas.region, 
        fechas.place, 
        fechas.tickets, 
        fechas.directions, 
        fechas.flyer,
        seo_sitemap.title,
        seo_sitemap.description,
        seo_sitemap.url,
        seo_sitemap.array_tags              
            FROM fechas 
                INNER JOIN paises ON fechas.city = paises.id_pais
                INNER JOIN seo_sitemap ON seo_sitemap.id_articulo = fechas.ID
        WHERE 
            CONCAT(fechas.place,' ',fechas.region,', ',paises.nombre,', ',( 
            CASE fechas.month
                WHEN 01 THEN 'Enero'
                WHEN 02 THEN 'Febrero'
                WHEN 03 THEN 'Marzo'
                WHEN 04 THEN 'Abril'
                WHEN 05 THEN 'Mayo'
                WHEN 06 THEN 'Junio'
                WHEN 07 THEN 'Julio'
                WHEN 08 THEN 'Agosto'
                WHEN 09 THEN 'Septiembre'
                WHEN 10 THEN 'Octubre'
                WHEN 11 THEN 'Noviembre'
                WHEN 12 THEN 'Diciembre'
            END),' ',fechas.dates,' de ',fechas.year) 
        LIKE '%string_busqueda%'
        AND seo_sitemap.id_tabla = 1
        AND fechas.status_fecha = statusFecha  ;
END IF;

END$$
```

And the MYSQL ERROR is:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ELSE SELECT CONCAT(fechas.year,'-',fechas.month,'-',fechas.dates) AS fecha' at line 34
```

Thanks a lot again.

Comment: Please post the error code and message.

Comment: Sorry. Is this `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ELSE
    SELECT 
        CONCAT(fechas.year,'-',fechas.month,'-',fechas.dates) AS fecha' at line 34` Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i think u cant use delimiter

why u need delimiter??

i try this code and working fine

```
CREATE PROCEDURE extraer_fechas(
    statusFecha SMALLINT(5),
    string_busqueda VARCHAR(50)
)
BEGIN

IF string_busqueda = "false" THEN
    SELECT
        CONCAT(fechas.year,'-',fechas.month,'-',fechas.dates) AS fecha_php,
        fechas.ID, 
        fechas.dates, 
        fechas.month, 
        fechas.year, 
        paises.nombre AS city,
        fechas.region, 
        fechas.place, 
        fechas.tickets, 
        fechas.directions, 
        fechas.flyer,
        seo_sitemap.title,
        seo_sitemap.description,
        seo_sitemap.url,
        seo_sitemap.array_tags
            FROM fechas 
                INNER JOIN paises ON fechas.city = paises.id_pais 
                INNER JOIN seo_sitemap ON seo_sitemap.id_articulo = fechas.ID
            WHERE seo_sitemap.id_tabla = 1
            AND fechas.status_fecha = statusFecha
        ORDER BY 
        fechas.month,
        fechas.dates,
        fechas.year 

;ELSE
    SELECT 
        CONCAT(fechas.year,'-',fechas.month,'-',fechas.dates) AS fecha_php,
        fechas.ID, 
        fechas.dates, 
        fechas.month, 
        fechas.year, 
        paises.nombre AS city,
        fechas.region, 
        fechas.place, 
        fechas.tickets, 
        fechas.directions, 
        fechas.flyer,
        seo_sitemap.title,
        seo_sitemap.description,
        seo_sitemap.url,
        seo_sitemap.array_tags              
            FROM fechas 
                INNER JOIN paises ON fechas.city = paises.id_pais
                INNER JOIN seo_sitemap ON seo_sitemap.id_articulo = fechas.ID
        WHERE 
            CONCAT(fechas.place,' ',fechas.region,', ',paises.nombre,', ',( 
            CASE fechas.month
                WHEN 01 THEN 'Enero'
                WHEN 02 THEN 'Febrero'
                WHEN 03 THEN 'Marzo'
                WHEN 04 THEN 'Abril'
                WHEN 05 THEN 'Mayo'
                WHEN 06 THEN 'Junio'
                WHEN 07 THEN 'Julio'
                WHEN 08 THEN 'Agosto'
                WHEN 09 THEN 'Septiembre'
                WHEN 10 THEN 'Octubre'
                WHEN 11 THEN 'Noviembre'
                WHEN 12 THEN 'Diciembre'
            END),' ',fechas.dates,' de ',fechas.year) 
        LIKE '%string_busqueda%'
        AND seo_sitemap.id_tabla = 1
        AND fechas.status_fecha = statusFecha
;END IF

;end
```

Comment: Hi and thanks, but not working yet. `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ELSE
    SELECT 
        CONCAT(fechas.year,'-',fechas.month,'-',fechas.dates) AS fecha' at line 34`

Answer (score 0):

Try below it's working for me

```
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Routine DDL
-- Note: comments before and after the routine body will not be stored by the server
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `extraer_fechas`(
    statusFecha SMALLINT(5),
    string_busqueda VARCHAR(50)
)
BEGIN

IF string_busqueda = "false" THEN
    SELECT
        CONCAT(fechas.year,'-',fechas.month,'-',fechas.dates) AS fecha_php,
        fechas.ID, 
        fechas.dates, 
        fechas.month, 
        fechas.year, 
        paises.nombre AS city,
        fechas.region, 
        fechas.place, 
        fechas.tickets, 
        fechas.directions, 
        fechas.flyer,
        seo_sitemap.title,
        seo_sitemap.description,
        seo_sitemap.url,
        seo_sitemap.array_tags
            FROM fechas 
                INNER JOIN paises ON fechas.city = paises.id_pais 
                INNER JOIN seo_sitemap ON seo_sitemap.id_articulo = fechas.ID
            WHERE seo_sitemap.id_tabla = 1
            AND fechas.status_fecha = statusFecha
        ORDER BY 
        fechas.month,
        fechas.dates,
        fechas.year;
ELSE
    SELECT 
        CONCAT(fechas.year,'-',fechas.month,'-',fechas.dates) AS fecha_php,
        fechas.ID, 
        fechas.dates, 
        fechas.month, 
        fechas.year, 
        paises.nombre AS city,
        fechas.region, 
        fechas.place, 
        fechas.tickets, 
        fechas.directions, 
        fechas.flyer,
        seo_sitemap.title,
        seo_sitemap.description,
        seo_sitemap.url,
        seo_sitemap.array_tags              
            FROM fechas 
                INNER JOIN paises ON fechas.city = paises.id_pais
                INNER JOIN seo_sitemap ON seo_sitemap.id_articulo = fechas.ID
        WHERE 
            CONCAT(fechas.place,' ',fechas.region,', ',paises.nombre,', ',( 
            CASE fechas.month
                WHEN 01 THEN 'Enero'
                WHEN 02 THEN 'Febrero'
                WHEN 03 THEN 'Marzo'
                WHEN 04 THEN 'Abril'
                WHEN 05 THEN 'Mayo'
                WHEN 06 THEN 'Junio'
                WHEN 07 THEN 'Julio'
                WHEN 08 THEN 'Agosto'
                WHEN 09 THEN 'Septiembre'
                WHEN 10 THEN 'Octubre'
                WHEN 11 THEN 'Noviembre'
                WHEN 12 THEN 'Diciembre'
            END),' ',fechas.dates,' de ',fechas.year) 
        LIKE '%string_busqueda%'
        AND seo_sitemap.id_tabla = 1
        AND fechas.status_fecha = statusFecha  ;
END IF;
END
```